# Restart android service after app was killed

Tags: android, service, titanium, appcelerator

Please, I updated this text for a better understanding of my problem. 
I'm using Android services in my app to launch local notifications, exactly as described [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Notifications), on Appcelerator Wiki. The services run well as expected but if the application is removed from the recent apps tray or device was rebooted, services stop.

I would like to the service still running after the app is killed or restart service after reboot device. How can I do it using classic Titanium.

In iOS version of my app I'm using Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification and run very well, even after switching the device off and on. I wish that on Android worked the same way.

Thank You for any help.

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: would you like to have an application that restarts its service again and again even if you explicitly killed that malicious app? i wouldn't

Comment: If a user uses whatsapp on Android and needs to restart their device the WA notification service is restarted without the user having to open the app. My app is similar, ie notifications should continue to be issued even if the user restarts the device, unless they open the app and adjust the service to no longer acknowledge notifications.

Comment: no, they dont use "always ready/started/restarted services" - they use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for that

Comment: Thank you, @pskink !!! FCM is a solution for some situations here. Very well. But my example above wasn't good. Sorry! In my specific case I need launch a local notification from service like [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Notifications) I need to restart a service when the user power on the device.

Comment: Please, @pskink, I changed the text to explain my problem better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these two modules:

- https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager
- https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/blob/master/documentation/bootreceiver.md

There you can use the BootReceiver to restart your on boot and the AlarmManager should help with the service.

Comment: I'm using this module exactly. https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.Android.Tools/blob/master/example/BootReceiver/Service/tiapp.xml. But when the application is installed on the device it generates a second app called "BootCompleted". It is insane.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but your problem is in the tiapp.xml you should use your app activity name and not ".BootCompletedActivity" e.g. if your app is My Test App then activity name should be ".MyTestAppActivity"

```
<activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                    android:label="BootCompleted"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    android:name=".BootCompletedActivity"
                    android:persistent="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```